# $p(\lambda) = 0$ when $\deg p$ is minimal implies that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am unsure if the following Proof is correct would you please care to verify?

**SOME PRELIMARNY NOTATION**

- $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ means that $T$ belongs to the set of linear operators on the vector space $V$.
- Given an operator $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ and a polynomial $p(z) = c_0+c_1z+c_2z^2+\cdot\cdot\cdot+c_mz^m$. Then $p(T)$ denotes the operator $p(T) = c_0I+c_1T+c_2T^2+\cdot\cdot\cdot+c_mT^m$

> **Theorem.** Given that $V$ is finite dimensional, $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ and $v\in V$ such that $v\neq 0$. and $p$ is the
>   polynomial with the smallest degree such that $p(T)v = 0$ then every
>   zero of $p$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.

**Proof.** Assume that $p(\lambda) = 0$ equivalently $(z-\lambda)$ is a factor of $p$ consequently for some non-zero polynomial $q$ we have $p(z) = (z-\lambda)q(z)$ and thus the corresponding operator becomes $p(T) = (T-\lambda I)q(T)$ and since $p(T)v = 0$ it follows that $(T-\lambda I)q(T)v = 0$ furthermore since $p$ is the polynomial with the smallest degree satisfying $p(T)v = 0$ it follows that $q(T)v\neq 0$ since $\deg q<\deg p$ consequently $(T-\lambda I)v = 0$ and since $v\neq 0$ it follows that $Tv = \lambda v$ implying that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.

$\blacksquare$

I am skeptical because i  did not use the hypothesis that $V$ is finite dimensional and **the above proof seems to be suggesting that multiple eigenvalues correspond to the same eigenvector** $\huge!$

Comment: Only a problem at the end: You cannot deduce that $(T-\lambda I)(v)=0$. In fact, put $w=q(T)(v)$. As you have seen, $w\not=0$, and we have $(T-\lambda I)(w)=0$, this prove that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue. (You have used the fact that $V$ is finite dimensional to say that there exists non zero polynomials $Q$ with $Q(T)(v)=0$).

Comment: @Kelenner I am sorry but i still dont seem to follow what you are saying

Comment: Where have you a problem with my comment ?

Comment: @Kelenner I dont seem to understand your arguemnt concerning $(T-\lambda I)v = 0$

Comment: As you have written, you have $(T-\lambda I)q(T)(v)=0$, (and $w=q(T)(v)\not =0$). You cannot deduce from that that $(T-\lambda I)(v)=0$. You have in fact $(T-\lambda I)(w)=0$.